# Hierarchical weighted-least squares reggression

Tags: modeling, multilevel-analysis, heteroscedasticity, weighted-regression

I'm conducting a hierarchical regression with 3 steps and all continuous IV's and DV's, however my data is showing evidence of heteroscedasticity. Am I able to apply WLS methods to a hierarchical regression to correct the heteroscedasticity?